# multiple if/else statements with different variables: vscode snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write a snippet to make case-style statements in JavaScript quicker. Right now I have this, and it works:

```
    "long if-else": {
        "scope": "javascript,typescript,html",
        "prefix": "ie",
        "body": [
            "if ( $2 ) {\n\n} ${1/(.)/else if ( ) {\n\n} /g}else {\n\n}\n"
        ]
    }
```

it allows you to insert 0 or more else if statements in between the opening if and closing else by entering n characters after first tab and hitting tab again.

I would like the user (me) to be able to specify a value to go inside the brackets (like `myVar =`). I've tried setting up a variable to be evaluated after the transform, but it hasn't been read as a variable.

Comment: That is a very smart snippet use of the global flag.  I don't understand what you are looking for in the question though.  I thought you meant for the second tabstop but you mean in each  `else if` set of brackets?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you got it - I'd like to put the same value in all of the round brackets.

Comment: Of course, easy to `/else if (myVar =  ) {\n\n} /` in your transform but you can't put a tabstop or a variable inside a transform, the grammar allows only text at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a tabstop or another variable inside the replacement part of a transform.

You have to use a different approach if you want each if/else block to contain a different variable, like:

```
if (myVar == ) {

} else if (myVar == a) {

} else if (myVar == b) {

} else if (myVar == c) {

} else if (myVar == d) {

} else {

}
```

You have to list those variables first before generating each else if block.  Try this snippet:

```
"long if-else": {
  "scope": "javascript,typescript,html",
  "prefix": "ie",
  "body": [

    "if (myVar = $2) {\n",

    "${1/(\\w+)(,\\s*|\\b)/} else if (myVar = $1) {${2:?\n\n:\n}/g}",

    "} else {",
    "",
    "}",
    "$3"
  ]
},
```

Here is a demo to see how you input the variables:

[image]

---

You enter each of the myVar's as a comma-separated list and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It doesn't handle the zero-case though without some more complications.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not very sure that this what you are looking for ( may be ) like this

```
"long if-else": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript,html",
    "prefix": "ie",
    "body": [
        "if ( ${myVar} ) {\n\n} ${1/(.)/else if ( ) {\n\n} /g}else {\n\n}\n"
    ]
}
```

using this way the user (you) will have something like

```
if ( myVar ) {

 } else {

 }
```