# Make a vscode snippet for switch with number of cases

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm looking for a way to make a snippet for a switch where you can say how many cases you want.
Like:
`switch2` gives

```js
switch (variable) {
    case "value":
        # code...
        break;
    case "value":
        # code...
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

and `switch3` gives

```js
switch (variable) {
    case "value":
        # code...
        break;
    case "value":
        # code...
        break;
    case "value":
        # code...
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

is this even possible and if yes how?

Comment: use extension **Hypersnips** with regex prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in an interesting way with regular snippets.  You don't trigger it with something like `switch3` or `switch4` but some generic switch trigger and then you enter how many case statements you want.  Not as a single number, like 3 or 4 but by the number of characters you input - can be any characters like `....` for four case statements or `1234` for four case statements.

Here is the snippet (in your `snippets.json`):

```
"n case switch statement": {
  // "scope": "javascript,typescript",
  "prefix": "switchN",             // whatever prefix you want
  "body": [
    "switch ($2) {",
    "${1/(.)/\tcase \"value\":\n\t\t# code\n\t\tbreak;\n/g}}"
  ]
}
```

[image: demo of snippet for n cases in a switch statement]

[Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046868/multiple-if-else-statements-with-different-variables-vscode-snippet/61050519#61050519.]

Comment: @Viper How is this working out for you?